# How can I make tabview filled when I click?

Tags: swiftui

I made a system image label default style. But I want make system image label filled while I click it. How can I make it.

```
    TabView {
        HomeView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                    .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
            }
        DataView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Data", systemImage: "list.clipboard")
                    .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
            }
        SettingView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Setting", systemImage: "gear")
                    .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                    
            }
    }
```

Label filled when I click it. When not click it will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using a `TabView(selection: $selectedTab)`,
and a ternary conditional in the `.environment()`.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = "Home"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("HomeView")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, selectedTab == "Home" ? .fill : .none)
                }.tag("Home")
            
            Text("DataView")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Data", systemImage: "list.clipboard")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, selectedTab == "Data" ? .fill : .none)
                }.tag("Data")
            
            Text("SettingView")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Setting", systemImage: "gear")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, selectedTab == "Setting" ? .circle.fill : .none)
                }.tag("Setting")
        }
    }
}
```